# i need a client library in scala for redis cluster

Tags: scala, redis, redis-cluster

I have created a redis in Amazon Eleasticache with cluster enabled mode.
I have a client for scala([scala-redis](https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis)) but this client works fine in normal mode(cluster disabled mode) but not working in cluster mode.I'm getting error of MOVED 12351 127.0.0.1:7000.I searched many clients but i can't find one to support with cluster mode.
So please help me to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/etaty/rediscala is fairly active and it seems to support cluster mode.

Comment: Hey @manub i'm using that library but while using the rediscluster getting some "java.lang.NullPointerException" in implicit val executionContext = system.dispatchers.lookup(redisDispatcher.name).
 but the value for the varible is have the default value 
val dispatcher = RedisDispatcher("rediscala.rediscala-client-worker-dispatcher") 

you have any idea on this.
thanks

Comment: make sure the `application.conf` files are loaded properly, it's likely to be an issue related to this.

Comment: thanks manub, redis client was working fine but while connecting rediscluster i got the "NullPointerException" on clusterSlotsRef. I just use  the redis servers to  create redisCluster object. whether i need to define any cluster slot in the config or it will take dynamically from the redis server ?